# Cannot find KeycodeV2.dll, or invalid keycode

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, visual-studio-2003

I have a legacy application developed in vs2003 and crystal report 9 web based and installed on windows xp and its running very fine, I want to move this application from windowsxp to window2008 server and iis7 having vs2010 and crystal report xi is installed on that machine , when i tried to open any report I am getting the following error
Cannot find KeycodeV2.dll, or invalid keycode
i have  copy this dll in the bin folder as well as in system32 folder even i have registered this dll with regsvr32 but issue not resolved.
please help me in resolving this issue.