# Visual Studio 2003 Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, 64-bit, report

An unhandled  exception has occurred in a component in your application.

Cannot find KeycodeV2.dll, or invalid key code.

Visual studio 2003 64 bit Win 7 (On printing CR).

Comment: As far i understand from your VS version you have x86 dll on 64 bit machine. And again as far as i remember no 64 bit dll until vs2005. If you can fing 64 bit version of CR dll from VS2005 or higher and install to machine you try to run it could solve your problem.

Comment: I found 64 bit version of CR but it didn't work.!

Answer (score 0):

We solved a similar issue.

Environment running Win 7 64bit, application generated by VS2003 (.NET 1.1).

Solution was uninstall Crystal Reports, run CCleaner, reinstall Crystal Reports.

We understand the error occurred because something was wrong with Crystal installation or there was a conflict with an other installation.

Note: i think i should add a comment instead of post it as an answer, but i have not enough reputation to add a comment.

EDITED: btw, there is a similar unanswered post:
[Cannot find KeycodeV2.dll, or invalid keycode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486194/cannot-find-keycodev2-dll-or-invalid-keycode)

And i did some research and found some people purposing similar explanation (problem with the instalation).